# Terminal emulator in windows which can store commands

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, terminal-emulator

Is there any good terminal emulator program which will help me save commands so I dont have to  type them again and again . It is for communicating with a **serial port (COM port)** in windows and I have tried putty and serterm but they dont have this functionality. Do you know of any other free software which can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

the Windows command prompt has a history of commands. Pres F7 to open it:

> **F7: Shows list of all previous commands from command history**
>
> You can press "F7" key to get a list of all previously executed
>   commands and then you can use Up or Down arrow keys to cycle though
>   them. Press Enter to execute the selected command.

[image]

**(Image-) Source:**

http://www.askvg.com/ultimate-list-of-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-command-prompt-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Save the long, complicated command as a PowerShell script with a short, convenient name.

PowerShell is built into Windows 7. Create the script with Windows PowerShell ISE, or just type the command in a text editor and save the file with a '.ps1' extension. This page may be helpful if you haven't used PowerShell before:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx